# Message dm in chat Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I can't seem to find out how to make a way to have someone say !dm   and have it only go to the specified player. Here's an example:

CoolGuy's message:
"!dm Moogstir Hello"

Reciever (Moogstir):
"-CoolGuy
Hello"

Here's my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const Player = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`It's an owl! It's a Bagel! NO It's a ${bot.user.tag}`) 
 });

Player.on('message', (message) => {



    if (message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === `!dm ` + `${player.user.tag}` + `${message.content}`) {
        message.Player.sendMessage(`-${message.author}` + "\n" + 
`${message.content}`);
    }

 });
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Try replacing `sendMessage` with `send`. As `sendMessage` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

To send a message to the author of the message, use ``` message.reply(``); ```

If you want the message to go to someone other than the author, you need to get the recipients ID/username and pass that through a collection to find them. ex: `collection.find('username', 'myUsername');`

Also, `sendMessage` is depreciated and should just be `message.channel.send` if you are sending to a channel in your server.

You should read through the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) to get the basics down. Some of it might be confusing at first, but it will start making sense the more you play with it.

EDIT: I'm not sure why you named your client `player` instead of `client` or `bot`, but I would recommend changing that to avoid confusion later on.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a bunch! :D

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could go about this, but here is one of the most simple.

```js
//command: !dm @user <message>
let user = message.mentions.users.first(); //grabbing the user mention
user.send(<message here>);
```

After running your command `!dm`, the code finds the user mention, and then sends the user a `dm message`.

**Sidenote:** Why use two different clients as well? Either use `bot` or use `player`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still trying to do a lot with this, thanks!

Comment: No problem, but I made a mistake. It should be `message.mentions.members.first();`

Answer (score 0):

//dm command

```
bot.on('message', function(message){
  if(message.content.startsWith("!ddm")){

    var user = message.mentions.users.first();
    var text = message.content.split(' ').slice(2).join(' ');

    message.delete();

    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")){
      message.channel.send("Du hast leider keine Rechte dafür!")
      return;
    }

    if(message.author.id == "ID hier"){
      message.reply("Tja da hast du wohl keine Rechte für! Du stehst für diesen Command leider auf der Blacklist!")
      return;
    }

    if(!user) return message.channel.send("Du hast keinen User angegeben.");
    if(!text) return message.channel.send("Du hast keine Nachricht angegeben.")

    user.send(`**${message.guild.name}:**`)
    user.send(text)
  }
})
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain how your suggestion could help the issue.

Comment: This most likely solves OP's question, but adding some comments or an explanation would improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code. Note that this only works on discord.js

```js
const prefix = "REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR BOTS PREFIX";

client.on("messageCreate", async (message, args) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
  
  // DM Command
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${prefix}dm`)) {
    let userDmed = message.mentions.users.first();
    let msgToUser = args.join(" ").split(", ")[1];

    if (!userDmed) return message.reply({ content: `Who you wanna DM lol? (e.g. \`${prefix}dm @user, Hey wanna go to park?\`)` });
    if (userDmed.id == message.author.id) return message.reply({ content: "Are you an idiot? You can't dm yourself lmao."})
    if (userDmed.id == client.user.id) return message.reply({ content: "Ya know I can't send embed to myself idiot." });
    if (!msgToUser) return message.reply({ content: `Provide some message bro. (e.g. \`${prefix}dm @user, Hey wanna go to park?\`)` });

    let dmEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Someone has DM'ed you!")
      .setDescription(`**From:** ${message.author}\n**Their Message:** ${msgToUser}`)
      .setColor("#525254")
      .setFooter({ text: `From: ${message.author.tag}`, iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL() });
    userDmed.send({ embeds: [dmEmbed] });

    await message.reply({ content: `Your message has been send to **${userDmed.tag}**'s DM!` });
  };
});
```